# Is there a way to make a border in html+css?

Tags: html, css, header, border

I know this sounds kind of confusing but I am wondering if it is possible to make a thick border line where the header is supposed to be?

I will try to explain it by giving an image:
[image]

I want the top part of my website page to have a different color, and then the lower part another color.

Is there any way I could use a html/css code to make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

this is the way to do it but for a question like this you should researsh a bit and learn the basics

```css
.header{
  background-color:yellow;
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
  }
  .rest{
  background-color:black;
  width:100%;
  height:700px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="rest">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly, you can create a div and append following css:

border-top: 50px yellow solid;
background-color: #000000;

==============

In this way the header part will be only for design, you can't put a relative code inside the border.

If you want to use that space you can do the following:

```
<style type="text/css">

div.header {
text-align:center;
background-color: yellow;
color: #00000;
padding: 20px;
width: 100%;
}

div.body {
width: 100%;
backgroun-color: #000000;
color: #ffffff;
}
</style>

<div class="header">Title</div>
<div class="body">Content</div>
```

Hopefully will help you,
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can try having an element for your header, this way you can include content in it.

**HTML5** has added multiple new tags for better understanding, you can use the tag `header` for it and then define you content inside the tag `main`

For example:

```css
body {
  background: #FAFAFA;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: #3F51B5;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

main {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>This is the header</header>

<main>
  This is the content
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, you have to use CSS to do this
lets say you have.It doesnt matter if you are using HTML5 or HTML4 the code below is only example

```
<section>Header</section>
<article>Body</article>
```

now you need to add to your `<head></head>` , style tag

```
<style></style>
```

but if you are using HTML4 it must be

```
<style type="text/css"></style>
```

Now you need to select one of those and give them color, in my example I will give them both color

```
<style>
 section{
  background-color:#000000;
 }
 article{
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
 }
</style>
```

background-color neednt to be in hexadecimal like #FFFFFF it can be in rgb(0,0,0) or rgba(0,0,0,0).